# How to verify protobuf encoding is used in gRPC?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using gRPC for streaming telemetry data. Testing team wants to check if protobuf encoding is used by gRPC? Can anyone help me how I can verify that?

Is there a way to capture the send packets using Wireshark & verify if protobuf encoding is used?

Tried searching online but didn't get any useful results.

Comment: Please share more specific about your situation. What does the test team do?

Comment: Do you want to check that the encoded data is wrapped by protobuff?

Comment: Yes. How can I verify that?

Comment: Testing team wants to verify if the protobuf encoding is used under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to proceed.

**Boring - Look At the Documentation**

First is to consult the docs. A glance [here](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/) is pretty good confirmation.

Though it's important to understand that there's several layers of the network stack here - gRPC uses Protobuf to encode application messages that are transferred across networks using http/2, which in turn may be configured to use TLS encryption, all of which ends up being sent over tcp sessions.

So, yes, gRPC does use Protobuf, but that's not the end of it (there's http/2 and possibly TLS too). The Testing Team may need to fully understand all of that.

**Look At the Source Code**

The source code all appears to be open source, one could double check that.

**The More Interesting Way**

Thirdly, and I recommend doing this regardless of whether or not the documentation was adequate to answer your question, the more fun way using Wireshark!

Wireshark can be easily extended. Basically, WireShark can unpick gRPC all the way to the proto messages themselves (unless you've turned on any of the security features in gRPC, in which case Wireshark will get stymied by not knowing the encryption keys). Wireshark can do this, because it looks like gRPC uses http/2, which is a defined protocol, but won't know how to decode the messages being transported using http/2.

What you can do is to use your .proto file to help generate a dissector plug-in for Wireshark, so that individual messages can be decoded within Wireshark. See [here](https://grpc.io/blog/wireshark/), and [here](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Protobuf)

Okay, so that's a bit of work to implement, but it can be worthwhile, especially if "testing" is significant. What it means is that Wireshark, and a PCAP file in particular, can be an authoritive record of the telemetry stream that is independent of the software at either end of the telemetry link. Plus, it's a properly timestamped record, which might also be important.

You've also got a very powerful diagnostics tool for if anything is going wrong. E.g. if the telemetry data isn't looking right, where is the problem creeping in? Having a Wireshark plugin that can be used to examine the gPRC data all the way in to the message content is a useful tool.

The Wireshark PCAP file and dissection would also be a good way of seeing whatever else might be going on at the same time.

I've done this before, though I was using ASN.1 and created a system-specific ASN.1 dissector for Wireshark. Wireshark used in this way is very cool.